# Android Studio: Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am trying to start development on an Android app using Android Studio, but whenever I try to run the app I get the error `Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'` I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio multiple times on different computers (both running Windows 10) and every time I get the same error. I have researched the problem and have been unable to find a consistent solution. (or one that actually works) I am very new to Android development and am slightly at a loss as to what to do; any help on solving this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is not a problem with Android Studio, it's something to do with the android sdk (adb is a program that should be inside the platform-tools directory of your Android Sdk directory). Perhaps check that it is actually there...

Comment: As far as I can tell adb appears to be there; my platform-tools folder looks like this http://imgur.com/aalXCAE Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: does running "adb.exe version" in command line return something like "Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32"? If so, I would guess that android studio doesn't know where the android sdk actually is... since running the command it sais if failing is obviously working.

Comment: Ah yeah, found the solution; Android Studio had the location of the SDK as Android\Sdk\ with a capital S... apparently even Google can't be trusted to get the capitals right! Thanks for your help though, glad that's solved! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to @user3109468, Android Studio had the directory for the Android SDK wrong. In File>Project Structure make sure the directory for the SDK is correct; mine was `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk` (Google had given sdk a capital "S" for some reason...)

Answer (score 8):

Uncheck: `enable adb integration` from `Tools>Android` and re-enable it.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This might be because of windows virtual memory problem.
Try running adb from command line. something like
`adb version` BTW, platform-tools would be located in
`c:\Users\<your userid>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools`

How much it takes from you firing a command and actually gets an answer ? 
if it takes more than 5 seconds, then android studio times out waiting for an answer and throws up an error.

How to fix ? 
close all your program ( Process ? ) 
and go to control panel -> System->advance System settings-> Advanced tab->performance->settings->Advance->Virtual memory change

Try to reduce virtual memory size. Fr e.g. If it's 4096Mb make it 2048Mb ( both initial and maximum) It will ask to restart, so restart and get yourself a cup of coffee, because it will take a while. Then, once your system is up , try running adb version. Does it run quickly ? If yes, problem is fixed. Go back to virtual memory and increase it's size to the one before, and that's it.

BTW, I noticed in my case that simple hello world program was taking 20 sec to execute on my machine before fixing virtual memory problem.

Comment: Thank you!!!! After 2 days with this trouble, with that I was able to fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Android SDK location and Android NDK location is correct.

1. Go to File -> Project Structure.
2. Set the Android SDK location and Android NDK location.[image]