# Android Studio: "Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'"

Tags: android-studio, adb

I am presently unable to do app testing on Android Studio, and I don't know what to do next. I've been getting the error "Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'" when I try to run an emulator. I don't think I changed anything on my system to make it happen, though I usually update any packages Android Studio recommends. I've Googled and that has given me a number of things to try, but I'm no further on.  I've tried the following:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling platform-tools - I even downloaded version 23 (I'm currently on 24) and replaced 24 with that, but that didn't work.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio - this worked for a day, but took hours, so I can't just do it every time.
- Checking adb.exe exists and the path is correct etc. - adb.exe exists in C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools and it seems ok.
- Anti-virus software blocking adb.exe - turned Firewall off; didn't help.
- Ran adb from the command line - runs ok, but when I type "adb devices", I get an empty list. If I go into Android Studio and start a device manually from the AVD Manager, and then do "adb devices" again, this time the running device shows up
- The location of "where adb" seems to be correct - I'm wondering whether Android Studio is looking in the wrong place for it. Is there a way to check the path?
- Went to the platform-tools folder and typed "adb tcpip 5555" - it said it was starting the daemon, and then that it had started successfully, but that still didn't help
- Disabled "Enable ADB integration" option, and then re-enabled it. Didn't help.  Then tried killing the adb server from the command line in between disabling/enabling. Tried restarting AS in between as well, still didn't help.

I'm stuck now, and I don't know what else to try. Would anyone suggest anything else I could try?

Also, I reckon I could temporarily push the app to the device using the command line, but I'm not sure what to push if I'm only testing, as I don't have an apk file (I think).  Which file would I push over to the emulator? And how do I do that? The emulator appears to be called emulator-5554.

I am on Windows 10, and have upgraded to the latest Android Studio (2.1.3).

Comment: Also tried "Clean Project" and "Clean cache" (I think that's what it's called) - neither made any difference.

Comment: Should also have made it clearer that I get the message when I try to run the project, and the screen that normally lists available devices has none listed.  They are still available in the AVD Manager, though, and I can run them from there - in theory I assume I can then use the command line to push the app to the device, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: You have network firewall? (no on your local machine but on your company network), which antivirus you use?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, I'm not on a network at all. I use MacAfee antivirus.

Comment: I just went through my Firewall settings, and adb.exe is definitely listed as 'allowed'.  I even gave it full permissions to access everything, but that still didn't help.

Comment: This is what help me but that for Avast :/ - http://rmarcejaeger.com/2016/04/30/solution-how-to-fix-android-studios-unable-to-obtain-result-of-adb-version-error/
Also might help - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183264

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037002/android-studio-unable-to-obtain-result-of-adb-version)

Answer (score 8):

***Preface: Although my answer focuses on Android Studio's perspective of ADB errors, I'm sure it is helpful for Windows ADB debugging in general!***

Wow, I understand the frustration from debugging for hours on long, here is my take on this strange error!

I used to get **"Unable to detect adb version, adb output:"** on Android Studio while trying to "run" the app onto the phone...  and no devices showed up when phone was connected to PC.

I had tried all these (from different SO answers) **but none of them worked!!!**:

- "Invalidate cache and restart" from `File` toolbar.
- Turn off and turn on USB debugging on phone multiple times
- Experimented with "MTP", "PTP", "Midi" and "Charging" modes to see if ADB detects something...
- Checked my anti-virus software to see if adding exceptions to the adb directory works...
- Installed various unnecessary C++ re-distributables
- Tried a different USB cable (and USB port)
- Restarted Android Studio and PC
- and even uninstalled and re-installed Android studio!

---

The problem finally was that the `platform_tools\adb.exe` file downloaded by the official SDK tool manager was corrupted! So I used to get windows error code 0xc0000142 on launching adb.exe from command prompt! :(

### SOLUTION:

For future readers (and victims xD) of the above ADB problem, please do the following:

1. Firstly, add the `platform_tools\` directory into the system path environment variable.
2. Go ahead and replace the following 3 files in your `platform_tools` (`C:\Users\{YourAccount}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`) directory. (Please backup the same folder before, just in case.)

[ADB kit (internal version number: 32)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1p7DiAcH2KisRw8NE_V_-s8zibKd3CDvl)

Comment: Install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio (win7). It saved me...

Answer (score 0):

Check in the task manager whether any other process ( mine was something daemon)might be using your port number. End that process.