# I was Using Eclipse neon and after a restart i got this error [ Unable to obtain result of 'adb version']

Tags: android, eclipse

Whenever i am opening Eclipse i am gertting this error.

-> [ Date and Time - adb] Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'.

**Please help.**

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Google has discontinued support of the ADT plugin for Eclipse. You should migrate to Android Studio in order to release apps for the most recent versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

[Android Studio: Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037002/android-studio-unable-to-obtain-result-of-adb-version) shows a similar error when using Android Studio. Be sure that Eclipse has the correct directory for your Android SDK. If that doesn't fix the problem check out [all of these other suggestions](https://www.google.com/search?q=Unable+to+obtain+result+of+%27adb+version%27&oq=Unable+to+obtain+result+of+%27adb+version%27&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.503j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) from googling the error message.