# Android Studio: Unable to obtain result of ADB version

Tags: android, adb, emulation

Whenever I attempt to run my android program, android studio throws this error: Unable to obtain result of ADB version. 
As a result, initializing ADB fails, and none of my created Virtual Devices are detected.

What helped me get around this problem was the post by prashant2400 
(e.g. Go control panel -> System->advance System settings-> Advanced tab->performance->settings->Advance->Virtual memory change). [Android Studio: Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037002/android-studio-unable-to-obtain-result-of-adb-version/41152380)

I had to meddle with this Virtual Memory paging file size, and ADB works after restarting the PC. However, the same problem happens again a day later when i resume coding... and I keep meddling with this page file size and restarting the workstation. How can I fix this problem permanently?

Emulator I am trying to run:
Nexus 5 API 26 (Playstore enabled / API 26 / Android8 / x86 / 1GB)

Android Studio:
2.3.3

PC Specs: 
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz 
8GB RAM
64 bit operating system, x64-based processor

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am thinking of buying more RAM (e.g. 8GB to 16GB) if it may help, but I think it's an issue with the latest build of Android Studio 2.3.3

Answer (score 1):

Managed to resolve this problem on my own. 
It turns out that it was a timeout issue whereby, the default 5s to wait to get the ADB version was too short. I simply had to increase the connection timeout settings to wait longer as per below.

[1] Go to: File --> Settings --> Tools (Expand Left Panel) --> Tasks

[2] Set the Connection timeout longer (default was 5secs). I set to 10secs.

Regards