# Android Studio - devices not available when I run a project

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

When I try to run a project, android studio cannot find either real or virtual devices, although they are available.

If I open AVD manager, I get two virtual devices in the AVD manager window. If I run either of these from AVD manager, it creates an emulator correctly. However, when I run the app ('run' then 'run app' from the toolbar), the 'Select Deployment Target' window opens, but then says 'Nothing to show' and no devices appear.

If I connect a real device, the Select Deployment target window still says 'Nothing to show'. Also, the 'allow USB debugging' window does not appear on the device, even though USB debugging is enabled.

It was all working ok two weeks ago. Having been away, I came back yesterday to find this problem. After that, last night I had a Windows 10 update and I have updated everything connected with Android studio, and I have also created a new basic 'Hello World' app, but still no change.

Can anyone help with a solution? Has anyone had the same problem? Is there some option or setting that might need changing?

Comment: try updating/reinstalling your adb driver. maybe it will fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Follow following steps for working real device:

First install google drivers as described on following link: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html

On windows open device manager and find your phone or some device named PCI and do right click and update driver then select browse my computer for drivers then go to path C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver
then press ok, wait for finishing.

Now reconnect your device, on your device you will get a pop-up to allow, after allowing that you would be able to see your device in android studio.

Comment: I have completely uninstalled Android Studio, including the user settings, and re-installed the latest version of everything, including google drivers as suggested by Shivam. I still have exactly the same problem, with a brand new Hello World test file.! I'm now completely out of ideas. This feels just like a very bad dream! Has anyone else any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I only posted this question after many hours of trying suggestions from this site and elsewhere. Just as I was about to give up, I found this:

[Android Studio: Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037002/android-studio-unable-to-obtain-result-of-adb-version)

Answer 2 from Prashant

and it worked! The problem was incorrect memory allocation slowing up my whole machine so that the time-out in Android Studio was exceeded. Reducing the virtual memory size solved the specific problem and also speeded up my whole machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed it for me, after trying the above in vain.

In my case it turns out there was an older version of adb.exe running in the background; from a previous HTC Sync Manager (for another Android phone) installation. When i stopped the service (and disabled it), it worked.

I got to this by displaying the event log to see the exact error shown when the issue above occurs, which was "adb server version (31) doesn't match this client (39); killing..."

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by removing a line in my `/etc/hosts` file (macOS Mojave) whereby I was pointing `10.0.2.2 -> localhost`.